# Sum of Random Variables compared with Multiplying Random Variable by Constant

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

$\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{var}}$I understand that when $X$ and $Y$ are normal, independent, random variables and $c$ is a constant:

(1). $\Var(X+Y) = \Var(X) + \Var(Y)$

(2). $\Var(c X) = c^2 \Var(X)$

I'm sure I'm looking at this incorrectly, but if $c = 2$ why does

$$\Var(X+X) \ne \Var(2X)$$

Comment: Because $X$ is not independent of itself, the first formula isn't applicable.

Comment: So, if I want my 'constant' to represent the combination of identical, independent copies of the same random variable, it would be more appropriate to use the $Var(X+X)$ formula?

Comment: Yes, precisely. However, note that this may be a recipe for making mistakes. Usually, when you say $X + X$, it is two copies of the same realisation of the random variable. For the sake of notational clarity, two random variables, even if i.i.d., are given two separate names $X_1$, $X_2$, if they are independently generated. We can probably go more into a *why* if you've come across the concept of a $\sigma$-algebra. If not, just take this as a 'rule' for now.

Comment: I think you're confused -- $X$ and $X$ aren't two independent copies of the same random variable.  They are EXACTLY THE SAME random variable.  Are you trying to discuss the case where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent but identically distributed?

Comment: yes, I meant $X_1$ and $X_2$ where $X_1=X_2$

Comment: No, I think you meant $X_1$ and $X_2$ where $X_1$ and $X_2$ are identically distributed. That doesn't make them equal.

Comment: fair enough, where $X_1$ and $X_2$ have the same mean and variance (and are normal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\operatorname{Var}(X+X)$ is indeed equal to $\operatorname{Var}(2X)$, which is $4\operatorname{Var}(X)$.

It would be an error to think that the equality $\operatorname{Var}(X+Y)=\operatorname{Var}(X)+\operatorname{Var}(Y)$ applies to $\operatorname{Var}(X+X)$.  It is not applicable because $X$ and $X$ are not **independent** random variables.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is a question where a little formalism will help.

A general expression is
$$V(X + Y) = V(X) + V(Y) + 2\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y).$$

If $X = Y$, then we have
$$V(2X) = V(X + X) = V(X) + V(X) + 2\operatorname{Cov}(X,X) \\
= V(X) + V(X) + 2V(X) = 4V(X).$$

Also,
$$V(0) = V(X + (-X)) = V(X) + V(X) + 2\operatorname{Cov}(X, -X)
\\= 2V(X) - 2\operatorname{Cov}(X,X) = 2V(X) - 2V(X) = 0.$$

The extreme cases where $X = Y$ and $X = -Y$ might help you remember
the general formula.

Comment: I understand why what you say is correct in most situations, but in my application, the random variables in question are estimated, rather than observed, so, while $X = Y$ in terms of mean and variance, $Cov(X,Y) = 0$ because they are still independent from one another despite having the same mean/variance.  Obviously, however, I wasn't specific about my application, so I appreciate your explanation